# BinTree haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I try to implement a function that returns a tree with the same structure but with all duplicate values ​​( nodes )

```
data BinTreeInt = Void | Node Int BinTreeInt BinTreeInt deriving Show

dupElem :: (Num a) => a -> BinTreeInt -> BinTreeInt
dupElem f Void = Void
dupElem f (Node n l r) = Node (f n) (dupElem f l)(dupElem f r)
```

I got this error:

```
P4.hs:382:32:
    Could not deduce (a ~ (Int -> Int))
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 dupElem :: Num a => a -> BinTreeInt -> BinTreeInt
      at P4.hs:380:12-51
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            dupElem :: Num a => a -> BinTreeInt -> BinTreeInt
          at P4.hs:380:12
    Relevant bindings include
      f :: a (bound at P4.hs:382:9)
      dupElem :: a -> BinTreeInt -> BinTreeInt (bound at P4.hs:381:1)
    The function ‘f’ is applied to one argument,
    but its type ‘a’ has none
    In the first argument of ‘Node’, namely ‘(f n)’
    In the expression: Node (f n) (dupElem f l) (dupElem f r)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Seems to be easy but... Haskell is not my love!

Comment: You've declared the type of the first argument to `dupElem` to be an instance of the `Num` type class, but then you attempt to call it like a function. (That said, the structure of `dupElem` looks a lot like the implementation of `fmap` if you were making `BinTreeInt` an instance of `Functor`.)

Comment: `f` in your case is a `a` ... but you try to apply this `n` to this `Num a`....

Comment: I guess with `duplicate` you want `f` to be an operation like *double a number* (something like `4 -> 8`, `3 -> 6`) right? In this case your signature should be `dupElem :: (Num a) => (a -> a) -> BinTreeInt -> BinTreeInt` (and ofc `BinTreeInt` might be misnamed) - and you should call it like `dupElem (*2) myTree`

Comment: Think what you mean by `(f n)` where both are Nums. Do you want to multiply them i.e. for f=2 will be doubling?

Comment: Please provide sample input and intended output to clarify what `dupElem` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you simply want to replace `n` with `f`, not apply `f` as a function to `n`.

```
dupElem :: (Num a) => a -> BinTreeInt -> BinTreeInt
dupElem _ Void = Void
dupElem f (Node n l r) = Node f (dupElem f l)(dupElem f r)
```

For instance, `dupElem 3 (BinTreeInt 1 (BinTreeInt 2 Void Void) Void)` would return `(BinTreeInt 3 (BinTreeInt 3 Void Void) Void)`.

Comment: I don't think so ("with the same structure but with all duplicate values")

Comment: I could read that as "duplicate the tree, with each node having the same (given) value", or "duplicate the tree with each node's value being duplicated [whatever that means]". I went with the interpretation that preserves the given type signature.

Answer (score 0):

According to your function signature "**a**" is constrained as a Num type but you are calling **a** as a function over n.

`dupElem :: (Num a) => a -> BinTreeInt -> BinTreeInt`

So my suggestion would be to change:

`Node (f n) (dupElem f l)(dupElem f r)`

for

`Node f (dupElem f l)(dupElem f r)`

as **chepner** suggested above.